# I don't understand this jquery code

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
$('#switcher button').click(function (event) {
    var bodyClass = this.id.split('-')[1];
    $('body').removeClass().addClass(bodyClass);
    $('#switcher button').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

What I don't understand the lines:

```
$('#switcher button').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

I think they are doing the same thing. Because "this" to me is the  "#switcher button"...
If I am wrong, who is "this..."?

Comment: this is referring to the current clicked `button`.. so they are removing the class from all `buttons` under `#switcher`.. and only applying it to the current clicked button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` refers to the particular button you clicked. So the first line removes the class for all of them, and then the next one adds the class to the individual button you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the class of `selected` from the button that lies within the element with the ID of `switcher`. The class is then being added back to the currently clicked button, which is represented by `this`